# Vertical align dropdown in a div

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, vertical-alignment

How can I place dropdown with known width in div with known width and height?vertical align doesnt help me.

```
    <div id="wrapper">
       <select id="dropdown" ></select>
    </div>

    #wrapper{
       border-style:solid;
       height:100px;
       width:200px;
     }

    #dropdown {      
      vertical-align:middle;
      width:80px;
    }
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxSPW/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
    border-style:solid;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#dropdown { 
   width:80px;
}
```